# git local commits disappeared when pulled origin

Tags: git

Steps:

1. Cloned Linux repository
2. Made some changes in code
3. Committed code:  `git commit -m "commit message1"`
4. Another commit:  `git commit -m "commit message2"`
5. `>git log`, displays the two commits as expected
   Here, I realized my code was not upto date, so I should test with latest
6. So, I updated my code: `git pull origin`
7. Now, when I do `>git log` I see only one commit that says

   Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/torvalds/linux

I understand what happened. But, how to see my commits as in step 5 back? Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually `git log` only shows the pushed logs, not the unpushed commits. To see it:

```
git log origin/master..HEAD
```

To see all un-pushed commit on all the branches try:

```
git log --branches --not --remotes
```